# Excel Placing spaced column data into rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have several thousand rows of spaced data like this:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
Status  Communication Types


New     Phone 
        Website 
        Phone 
        Phone 
        Email (Office) 






Open    Phone 
        Email (Office) 



Closed  Phone 
        Website 
        Email (Office)
```

The spacing is not consistent as it depends on the number of contact details contatined.

Is there a macro I can run or a formula I can use to get this data to show in rows like this?

```
Status    Phone    Phone2    Website    Email (Office)
```

Comment: No, you will have to write some VBA code yourself, there is nothing built in in Excel (besides the transposed paste, which is the closest built-in feature to this question).

Comment: Could you give me some indication of what code would work? Thanks

Comment: Because this is not a free code writing service you should start on your own and come back with your code when you got stuck or errors. People here usually won't write the code for you. Also this question is too broad to be answered. You would need to loop through the rows and reorder them. Maybe the transpose feature could be useful here.

Comment: I agree 100% with what [@Pᴇʜ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%e1%b4%87%ca%9c) said. I would just add that a cool trick to delete all blank rows is creating a table with ALL data (blank rows included), and then you order by value and delete the blank rows. Record the macro and maybe that can be the start of your code.

Comment: I have managed to get another version of the data with the contact information in multi line cells but when I have tried using text to columns it is only seeing the first line of the cell. i.e. If the data is phone: xxxxx website xxxxx when i use text to columns only the phone number shows. Is there another way to make the search see all the cells contents?

Answer (score 0):

I need more information before I can help you. When you say "Phone" in your data example, would it literally show in the cell as "Phone" or is there an actual phone number there? Like, where's the actual data values at, such as 123-456-7890?

Could you please edit your question to provide some dummy data? Also, is it always the same situation for New, Open, and Closed where New has those 5 communication types, Open has those 2 communication types and Closed has those 3 communication types? Or is it potentially different situations?